# Get color variables of corresponding color-scheme css

Tags: css, web

I use `color-scheme: light dark;` in my css code and want to use the background color set to buttons to set it to another element's background color, how can I get this value ?
Is there some names of variables set to css to get colors scheme used values ?

I already searched on internet but found nothing, perhaps bad search keywords, is this possible, if so, how ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer by searching "user agent stylesheet".

You can find the names there : https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords#System_Colors